# How to pass new Router to a variable in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created the project using vue-cli and I'm currently learning **vue-router**.

I want to use the **beforeEach** function for my authentication and all of tutorial that i have seen pass the **new Router** function to a variable like `var new_value = new Router`.

This is what my router looks like

**router.vue**

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

What I want to achieve is :

```js
var new_router = new Router({ // pass the value to new_router
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

When I do this I'm getting an error of `Cannot read property type`. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought the problem is about exporting.

```
var new_router = new Router({/*Your Options*/});
```

Do what ever you want:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  // Authentication Checking
});
```

And you must export

```
export default new_router;
```